# Check process in makefile

Tags: makefile

All,

I am currently having a makefile who have some code like:

```
.PHONY: start-server start-checker kill-server
kill-server:
    -pkill -f 'python3 start_server_host.py'

start-server:
    nohup python3 start_server_host.py >> server.out 2>&1 &

start-checker:
    nohup python3 checker.py ${ARGS} test >> checker.out 2>&1 &
```

`start-checker` needs `start-server`to be there. I am trying to figure out how to do something like:

```
start-checker:
   if not process start_server_host.py
     then start-server
   nohup python3 checker.py ${ARGS} test >> checker.out 2>&1 &
```

the goal is to start the `start-server`when not done to avoid having this manual action

Comment: Why don't you: 1) check that the server is running and, if not, start it in your `start-server` recipe, 2) declare `start-server` as a prerequisite of `start-checker`?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise against using makefiles for system administration tasks. I understand the apparent advantages (minimal boilerplate code for argument handling) is sweet. But I assure you it will come to bite you sooner or later.

to answer your question: modify `check-server` to depend on `start-server`. modify `start-server` to create a file named `start-server`. modify `kill-server` to delete the file `start-server`

now if you do `make start-server` the server will be started and a file named `start-server` will be created. if you do `make check-server` and the file `start-server` exists it will not invoke `start-server`. if you do `make kill-server` the file `start-server` will be deleted. if you do `make check-server` again the file `start-server` will be missing and `start-server` will be invoked first.

what happens when server crashes and the file `start-server` is not deleted? that is when this makefile sysadmin hackery will come to bite you.

again i strongly urge to not use makefiles for sysadmin tasks. I wrote in more detail as answer to a similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496793/script-or-makefile-to-automate-new-user-creation/497601#497601